# postgreSQL 9.1.18 installation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I downloaded PostgreSQL 9.1.18 version and I have windows 32 bit. I'm trying to  install this database first time in my computer so, when I start installing PostgreSQL 9.1.18 at the last step it shows me error.

Before the installation I created a folder in c drive with the name PostgreSQL then went to security tab and added account PostgreSQL and give full control. When I install PostgreSQL 9.1.18 I select this folder but again at the end same error occurred.

ERROR

> "Problem running post-install setup.Installation may not complete
>   correctly.the database cluster initialization failed"

Any help please

Comment: Please see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation . Provide the installer log file please.

Comment: from where i  find log file?

Comment: See the link above? Click on it. Details in there.

Comment: yes i check that link but to complicated.. when i try to delete using cmd like net user postgres /delete it shows  like this please check image...http://oi62.tinypic.com/hvcx08.jpg

Comment: I've already told you what you need to do. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation#Collect_the_installer_log_file

Comment: @CraigRinger i try to add log file but stack over flow said this is too long

Comment: Upload it to a 3rd party site and post a link. gist.github.com, pastebin.com, something like that

Comment: ok check that.. http://pastebin.com/0YKWRYES