# postgreSQL 9.1.18 version installation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I downloaded PostgreSQL 9.1.18 version and I have windows 32 bit. I'm trying to install this database first time in my computer so, when I start installing PostgreSQL 9.1.18 at the last step it shows me error.

Before the installation I created a folder in c drive with the name PostgreSQL then went to security tab and added account PostgreSQL and give full control. When I install PostgreSQL 9.1.18 I select this folder but again at the end same error occurred.

ERROR

"Problem running post-install setup.Installation may not complete correctly.the database cluster initialization failed"

and also i use cmd for this and enter command net user postgres/delete but when i enter it shows like this please check image..
[image](http://oi62.tinypic.com/hvcx08.jpg)

and also when i google i find that install postgreSQL in c: rather than program files. so when i create folder in c drive and give full admin rights and run installation during installation i select that folder but when installation is complete another folder is create in program files with the name PostgreSQL  in that folder and also all subfolders install in that folder

any help please

Update: Everything looks fine until `initdb`:

```
Executing batch file 'radB6293.bat'...
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "lenovo".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale English, United States.
initdb: could not find suitable text search configuration for locale English, United States
The default text search configuration will be set to "simple".

fixing permissions on existing directory C:/PostgreSQL ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
10
....
```

Comment: You already posted this.

Comment: yes i know but that question not posted correctly so i post whole problem in one question

Comment: OK. In future, please *edit the question* rather than re-posting. Otherwise you'll find questions get locked/closed quickly. For others, please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31603332/398670 for prior discussion, including my links to the relevant documentation for how to get the installer log file.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask helpful.

Comment: ok understood thank you

Comment: Get the installer log file from the location I already advised you of. Upload the installer log file and post a link to it. Without the installer log file it is unlikely anybody can help you.

Comment: I've updated your question with the relevant part of the installer log, showing the error. It's a weird one.  If you run the uninstaller, then remove the existing `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1` and `c:\postgresql` (this will DESTROY ANY DATA IN POSTGRESQL), delete the `postgres` user and delete the postgresql service, and re-try, does anything change?

Comment: before the installation i create folder in c:drive instead of program files and when i run the postgreSQL then i always select that folder but when installation is finished another folder is created in program files and also all subfolders exist in it.. check this image with c:postgresql image http://oi61.tinypic.com/2d0cep3.jpg.. and this with program files.http://oi62.tinypic.com/2u55i4g.jpg

Comment: i also delete everything infact postgres user and when i again install same error occured

Comment: also when i google i find use this command in cmd for delete net user postgres\delete but when i enter it show different result check image ..http://oi62.tinypic.com/hvcx08.jpg